# html css links visited

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

my links turn purple sometimes, probably becouse they are visited or something. I want to disable this from css.

How can i do this?

thanks in advance, yours lovely alexander

Comment: Just as an aside: in some cases - especially larger sites where users do a lot of reading/research - it's a good idea to style visited links differently from non-visited links so users can see where they have been before.

Comment: I would argue that it is **always** good to have `:visited` links easily distinguishable, maybe except for site elements such as navigation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selector a:visited.

```
a:visited {
  color : black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

by using the [visited pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pseudo_visited.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Simply set a CSS style which sets the colour for `<a>` tags.

```
a {color:blue;}
```

There are separate pseudo tags for `a:link`, `a:hover`, `a:visited` and `a:focus`, but unless they're being set elsewhere, you shouldn't need to specify them - if you just specify the style for `a` as above, it should apply whatever the state of the element.

If the psedo styles are being set and you need to override them, then you'll need something like this:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover {color:blue;}
```

(of course you can remove any of the above that you don't want to override)

Answer (score 2):

In CSS write:

```
a:visited 
{
   color: #f00; /*where #f00 is your hexadecimal colorcode, you can use "blue" or an RGBa value too!*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the visited property for your links.

```
<style type="text/css">
a:visited {color: #000000}
</style>
```